# Why can't i set a thumbnail on the Taskbar using DwmSetIconicThumbnail?

Tags: c++, windows, taskbar

I need your help for a project at my job.
The main software, using 4D language, works as a MDI, it creates many windows included in the main window. The main issue is that we have a lot of windows and we need an easy way to switch from a window to another.
We decided to create a little c++ plugin which is a dll to resolve this issue.

This plugin will create a tab on the taskbar for each window opened like Windows Explorer. The creation and the deletion of tabs already works.

But the current problem is that no thumbnail is set on the Tab.

The parameter given is the ID of the window from the main software. The method called `PA_GetHWND` is the method given by 4D to obtain the handle of the window using the `windowID`.
I have already check where is the problem. The bitmap created from the window already exists and is good. For this test, i put the bitmap in the clipboard and paste it on Paint and the Bitmap was good.

Here is the code introducing the method to refresh the bitmap on the tab.

```
bool CManageTaskBar::UpdateWindow(long WindowID) 
{

    HRESULT res;
    HDC hdcScreen;
    HDC hdcWindow;
    HDC hdcMemDC = NULL;
    HBITMAP hbmScreen = NULL;

    //Get the Handle from 4D
        HWND nHandle = (HWND)(PA_GetHWND((PA_WindowRef)(WindowID)));

    // Retrieve the handle to a display device context for the client 
    // area of the window. 
    hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
    hdcWindow = GetDC(nHandle);

    // Create a compatible DC which is used in a BitBlt from the window DC
    hdcMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow);

    // Get the client area for size calculation
    RECT rcClient;
    GetClientRect(nHandle, &rcClient);

    // Create a compatible bitmap from the Window DC
    hbmScreen = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcWindow,rcClient.right - rcClient.left, rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top);

    // Select the compatible bitmap into the compatible memory DC.
    SelectObject(hdcMemDC, hbmScreen);

    // Bit block transfer into our compatible memory DC.
    if (!BitBlt(hdcMemDC,
        0, 0,
        rcClient.right - rcClient.left, rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top,
        hdcWindow,
        0, 0,
        SRCCOPY))
    {
        MessageBox(nHandle, L"BitBlt has failed", L"Failed", MB_OK);
        //goto done;
    }

    ITaskbarList3* ptbl = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(my_CLSID_TaskbarList, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, my_IID_ITaskbarList3, (LPVOID*)&ptbl);


    BOOL fForceIconic = TRUE;
    BOOL fHasIconic = TRUE;
    res = DwmSetWindowAttribute(nHandle, DWMWA_FORCE_ICONIC_REPRESENTATION, &fForceIconic, sizeof(fForceIconic));
    res = DwmSetWindowAttribute(nHandle, DWMWA_HAS_ICONIC_BITMAP, &fHasIconic, sizeof(fHasIconic));

    if (hbmScreen)
    {
        res = DwmSetIconicThumbnail(nHandle, hbmScreen,0);//DWM_SIT_DISPLAYFRAME);
    }

    DeleteObject(hbmScreen);
    DeleteObject(hdcMemDC);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);
    ReleaseDC(nHandle, hdcWindow);

    return true;
}
```

The calls to `DwmSetWindowAttribute` return Invalid Handle. This handle works to get a bitmap but not to set an attribute.

And the call to `DwmSetIconicThumbnail` returns `E_INVALIDARG` maybe because the handle given is wrong.

Why cannot I set an attribute to this handle and why the call to set the thumbnail returns E_INVALIDARG ?

Thanks to everyone who will take care of my problem.
It's my first question, be friendly please :)